# PDO - quotes are generating MySQL syntax error

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm trying to bind parameters in what I think is the correct way, but I get a 1064 error from MySQL, suggesting that there are too many quotes involved. The written code looks like this:

```
$db_host = 'localhost';
$db_username = 'root';
$db_password = 'Password123';
$db_database = 'db_test';

$dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host", $db_username, $db_password);
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("DROP DATABASE :db_database;");
$stmt->bindParam(':db_database', $db_database, PDO::PARAM_STR, 7);
$stmt->execute() or exit(print_r($stmt->errorInfo(), true));
```

and displays the error message:

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near ''db_test'' at line 1 )

It worked fine when I inserted the variable `$db_database` the wrong way, i.e. directly into the sql syntax. Also, I have checked that magic_quotes are turned off, if that has any impact on it. Right now I'm stuck, because it feels like I have done things correctly (but obviously I haven't). Can anyone see the error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. You are using emulation it seems, because the database wouldn't even let you `PREPARE` this (set `$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES,false);`)
2. You can NOT name identifiers (column/table/databasenames), functions, etc. in parameters, that is not how prepared statements work, you can only send 'true' strings / floats / ints. In short, if you need an identifier or function name somewhere, it should be in the query before your `->prepare()` it.

Comment: So basically, I'm using PDO's in a manner that it really never was intended for?

Comment: Not strictly `PDO` related: you are using _prepared statements_ in a way that was not intended. The whole 'plan' of a query (which databases / tables / columns are involved, etc.) should be known by the time of the `prepare`, the rest is just parameters. Rule of thumb could indeed be: if you can't put `'somestring'` (including quotes) in the place of your placeholder without making the query syntactically invalid, it wasn't meant to be boundable with a parameter.

Comment: Would a better way to do it be to just simply insert the variable $db_databse directly in the query, since it's nothing any outside user can input anyway, and thus is not susceptible to malicious code?

Comment: If it is 100% guaranteed not user generated, and internal in your code, yep, just make the raw query.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
$dbh->query("DROP TABLE `{$db_database}`");
```

You should stick with prepare/execute when working with tables rather than databases. Also, you will only see a performance increase with prepare and execute when issuing multiple similar queries. Quote [From the PHP Manpage](http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

> For a query that you need to issue multiple times, you will realize
>   better performance if you prepare a PDOStatement object using
>   PDO::prepare() and issue the statement with multiple calls to
>   PDOStatement::execute().

Comment: You know that `->quote()` adds, you know, quotes? Which are the source of the OPs problem?

Comment: Better than leaving the user input un-escaped. It also escapes special characters, `PDO::quote() places quotes around the input string (if required) and escapes special characters within the input string`

Comment: You are missing the point: `DROP TABLE 'databasename';` is a sql SYNTAX ERROR. We are dealing with an identifier here, not a string.

Comment: Ahh, understood, so then wrap it with backticks (`)

Comment: The output of `'\`'.$dbh->quote().'\`';` would still be wrong, so we can simply not use the `quote()` function, but if it's user supplied, a `\`` may be in there, so we can't just add it in. The only reliable way to make it safe is whitelisting, and you can query for valid identifiers in the `INFORMATION_SCHENA` tables.

Comment: Im not saying to wrap $dbh->quote, but to ditch it and just use backticks. See the answer above.

Comment: SO, now `$db_databasename='foo\`; DROP DATABASE bar';`. A no go, whitelisting I tell ya.

Comment: So, to circumvent that, `str_replace('\`', '\`\`', $db_databasename)` ? It would then fail since a database named `foo\`; DROP DATABASE BAR';` does not exist?

Comment: Not quite, as you can't just 'restart' the identifier with an extra `\``. It would be easier to check `if(!in_array($db_databasename,$dbh->query('SHOW DATABASES')->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN))){ echo 'database does not exist';}`